# how to create dynamic ui from api response

Tags: android, fragment

Is it possible to add fragments dynamically,something like I got a server response for the views in the field, like, how many edit text, buttons, text views,and, URLs, other documentation.So I need to manage it and set the views according to that.You cannot add activity like that because i need to register it in manifest file.The views are dynamicaly changing.

Comment: yes definitely it is possible.learn how to create dynamic ui

Answer (score 2):

Of course, you can. You can setup any layout you want. You register the activity but you do not register layout.
inside `onCreate` method you can add this:

`setContentView(mycustomview);` or `setContentView(R.layout.layoutfromresources);`

you can manage your layouts:
for example,
`root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);`

`root.addView(newView);` before and after HTTP responce.

In the `AndroidManifest.xml` the programmer just says,
"Let such activity be!"

```
<activity
            android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_alias"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" 
            android:theme="@style/Theme.SelectDate">

        </activity>
```